# Finding left childs that are leaves in a tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to find count of left childs which are leaves in a tree. I want to do recursive but I couldn't take an output other than zero.Thanks.

```
public int countLeftChildren() {

    if (nodex != null) {

         if(nodex.left != null) {

             nodex = nodex.getLeft();
             countLeftChildren();

            }
            if(nodex.right != null) {

                nodex = nodex.getRight();
                countLeftChildren();

            }
            if(nodex.left == null && nodex.right == null && nodex==nodex.getParent().getLeft()) {
              countLeftChildren++;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace `nodex.getParent().getRight()==null` with `nodex.getParent().getLeft()==nodex`, to identify that the current node is in fact a left child. Whether there is also a right child should be irrelevant.

However, your approach is a bit odd. this is how I would code it:

```
class MyNode {
   ...
   public int countLeftChildren() {
       int cnt = 0;
       if(left != null) {
           cnt += left.countLeftChildren();
       }
       if(right != null) {
            cnt += right.countLeftChildren();
       }
       if(left == null && right == null && getParent().left ==this){
          cnt = 1;
       }
       return cnt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single variable `nodex` for nodes. This results in unexpected behaviour: the algorithm won't traverse the entire tree, but the left-most path of the tree. And unless the parent of the leaf at the end of the path hasn't got a right child, the algorithm will always result in 0. Apart from that this code won't even compile due to the fact that the last return-statement is missing (all return-statements are inside the if-clause). You'll have to use another approach for this kind of problem:

```
countLeafsLeft(node n)
    if n == NULL
        return 0

    //this node is a leaf and the left child of it's parent
    if n.left == NULL AND n.right == NULL AND n.parent != NULL AND n.parent.left == THIS
        return 1

    int tmp = 0

    if n.left != NULL
        tmp += countLeafsLeft(n.left)
    if n.right != NULL
        tmp += countLeafsRight(n.right)
```